# C++: Why does volatile access needs sequencing?

Tags: c++, volatile

I went through the code below on a C++ quiz site. It also provides an explanation. I am aware that `volatile` qualifier signals to the compiler that the value of the variable may be changed by some other factors. The explanation by the site adds that accessing `volatile` should be sequenced. Why and how it should be sequenced?

I don't understand what they mean by *unsequenced side-effects* and *scalar object*. Please also make it clear.

```
#include <iostream>
volatile int a;
int main() {
  std::cout << (a + a);
}
```

> The issue here is not the missing initializer of the variable `a` - it
>   will implicitly be initialized to 0 here. But the issue is the access
>   to a twice without sequencing between the accesses. According to
>   §1.9¶12, accesses of `volatile` glvalues are side-effects and according
>   to §1.9¶15 these two unsequenced side-effects on the same scalar
>   object result in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not defined which one of the two accesses occurs first, here.

In this case of a symmetric addition operation it does not matter.

But consider a different operation that's not symmetric:

```
std::cout << a * (a+1);
```

Now, consider a `volatile` object that, due to external factors, gets automatically incremented after every access. Let's say that, for example, `a` is some kind of a hardware register. As I said, let's say that every time it's accessed it gets incremented, so the hardware register contains the value 4 on the first access, and 5 on the second access. A simple counter.

Then, if the first access was for the left hand side of the multiplication, and the second access was for the addition operation on the right hand access of the multiplication, then this becomes

```
std::cout << 4 * (5+1);
```

But if the first access was for the right hand side, and the second access was for the left hand side, this becomes

```
std::cout << 5 * (4+1);
```

That's why having `volatile` objects is not enough. The operations must be sequenced.

Comment: But does it really result in undefined behavior, or merely unspecified?

Comment: @MarkB, it is UB: _If a **side effect** on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, and they are not potentially concurrent (1.10), the behavior is undefined._ And accessing a volatile object is a side effect

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I'd say your corollary is a bit misleading. This particular problem exists due to `volatile` nature of the `a` object. Being it not `volatile` and the problem is gone, if you don't have a concurrent access of course. And if you have there might be a race condition and `volatile` has no advantages in such a case.